# Postgresql, export a sql file to create database

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, dbeaver

With MySql Workbench, I could create all tables of a database with EER-Diagram, and then do File/Export/Forward Engineer SQL Create Script to generate a sql file that creates the db plus all tables of the db. In Postgresql, with pgAdmin4 or DBeaver, I have created all tables under database/schema, is there any similar way to generate a sql file to create the db and all tables of the db?

Comment: This is usually done with the [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) command line tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You export only `schema without data` using `pg_dump` in `psql [terminal]`:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -s databasename > backup.sql
```

or with `Pgadmin4`

1. Go to Tool -> Backup and select `only schema` in the `Dump option`.

[image: Screenshot of Backup]

Comment: it backs up as a binary file instead of a sql file with pgadmin

Comment: binary? not if I use file.sql name and "Plain" in format field